# Ubuntu : ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and just installed a fresh version of Android Studio, and written Hello World program, and now trying to run it, but everytime I am getting:

```
ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb" and click 'Restart'
```

I found many questions on SO, but none of them solution worked for me...

Comment: you can kill adb from your system monitor...

Comment: @RikzPatel in System Monitor, I am not getting any adb

Comment: You are running on Emulator or real device?

Comment: @theJango I am getting this error, so not able to run neither on Emulator nor Device ... but as per your question.. So I would like to run it on Emulator first of all

Comment: Run this command from Terminal inside Android Studio.
adb kill-server && adb start-server

Comment: if your adb is working that will be display into System Monitor process.... are you make sure that you give permission of adb. @sun

Comment: @theJango I just opened android-studio folder and opened terminal then run this command: adb kill-server and getting The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb ... Is It correct ? Shall I install it ?

Comment: Locate 'adb' bin file  from your sdk folder, it should be at 
/Users/YOUR_PATH/SDK_PATH/platform-tools , replace YOUR_PATH & SDK_PATH from your system path. Then Open terminal there and run this command. Right click on your project go to Module settings ---> Go to SDK to locate sdk in your system.

Comment: @theJango yes 'adb' is inside: /home/sun/Android/Sdk/platform-tools (when I run adb kill-server at this point, still showing - The program 'adb' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb [SO SHALL INSTALL IT ?]) or what to do ? and Module Settings > /home/sun/Android/Sdk... what's next ?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error mostly comes if you have already opened eclipse and studio both.

**Solution:** Close Eclipse if opened and "**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart....**" from your android studio.